# why I can not create a VC++ empty project on my windows using vs 2015 ,vs2017,vs2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

in VS 2015, there is a warning dialog 'null' is null or is not object when i try to create a VC++ project:

[image]

then i get another warning:

> error from HRESULT:800A138F

[image]

in VS 2019 i got the warning:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object,

[image]

Comment: my windows version Windows 10 1903

Answer (score 0):

You could try steps below to resolve this issue:

1.Windows+R and enter `regedit` to open `Registry Editor`, make sure the value data of `Enabled` key is set to zero.

[image]

We can find the key here:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\FipsAlgorithmPolicy`

2.Restart VS to check if the issue goes away, if it persists, close all vs instances and delete all folders under path: `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio` . It will clean all VS cache to reset the VS settings.

Note: `AppData` is a hidden folder.

Comment: The "error from HRESULT:" prompt box appears, it is likely that the installation should not install the part that should be installed.
1, open the visual studio installer
2, select "Desktop development with c++ ", and then click "Modify" in the lower right corner

Comment: **"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"** : I suggest you try running the command line: `devenv /installvstemplates` In order to avoid the problem of not installing files, I suggest you try to download and install from [the official website](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/zh-hans/downloads/?rr=https%3A%2F%2Fsocial.msdn.microsoft.com%2FForums%2Fpt-BR%2F30dacb7c-7742-4ad9-b45f-847a0d666800%2Fvs2015%3Fforum%3Dvstudiozhchs) again.